# How to update a session variable

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables, multipartform-data

I am creating a multi-step form with Ajax and would like to change text displayed based on the value of a form field. I thought that a good way to do this would be with a session variable. How do I tell the session to update with the new field value? Currently, the session only seems to store the initial value, but not any updates to it. So if a user enters "John" as the first name and then later goes back and changes it to "Frank," "John" is the name stored.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['formStarted'] = true;
$_SESSION['timestamp'] = date("M d Y H:i:s");
$_SESSION[$key] = $value;

<p>Your name begins with the letter <?php if ($_SESSION['name'] =='Frank') 
  {echo 'F';}?><p>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#form").validate({
   //...
   submitHandler: function(form) {

   //... 
   $(form).ajaxSubmit({               
     type: "POST",
     data: {
       name : $('#name').val(),
//...
     },
     dataType: 'json',
     url: '../ajaxtest.php',
     error: function() {alert("There was an error processing this page.");},
     success: 
       function(data) {
         $('#output1').html(data.message.join(' ')).show(500);
         $('#ouput1').append(data);
//...
```

ajaxtest.php:

```
session_start();

$expected = array( 
'name'=>'string', 
//...
);

//...

$return['message']=array();
if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
   $return['message'][] = '' . htmlentities($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
   } 
//...
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: I don't see a way that could be a PHP problem. It looks like a code problem. Post your ajax code that submits the request and prefereably the output of some var_exports of $key and $_SESSION on line 6.

Comment: What event are you using to trigger the ajax code?

Comment: @Jim The ajax code is being triggered by a submit button. I am using an accordion with different parts of the form within each section.

Comment: What does `ajaxtest.php` look like?

Comment: @Paystey I posted the ajax code.

Comment: OK Post the full sequence of events from intial page load (PHP) to submitting ajax (Javascript) with any associated HTML elements on that page followed by the PHP code that it's submitting to.

edit: damn enter key posting, I'll press shift this time. 

I can't see where any defaults are set or where it sets the new value

Answer (score 2):

You can update the `$_SESSION` like you update a simple variable. The `$_SESSION` is a global var and you can access it after `session_start()` declaration.

It's not required to `unset` the `session` when you want to change because you are working at the same `memory` address.

For example:

**index.php**

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['key'] = 'firstValue';
```

**anotherpage.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   session_regenerate_id() // that's not required
   $_SESSION['key'] = 'newValue';
```

**checkpage.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   echo $_SESSIOn['key'];
```

**Navigation**

```
index.php -> anotherpage.php -> checkpage.php // output 'newValue'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a persistent session between pages, you need to call `session_start` at the start of *every* script that the session should apply to, not just the first one.

The [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) for `session_start` say that the function will cause the session to persist if it already exists.

Comment: @Zach Thank you. I do have a session_start at the start of every page. The problem seems to be that the initially entered value persists even if it is later changed.

Comment: Are you sure you're setting `$_SESSION['name']` in the ajaxtest.php? Try clearing your browser cookies and resubmitting the form. If it's empty, then your form isn't setting that variable. Also, try `var_dump($_SESSION)` to see the entire session state.

Comment: @Zach I did a var_dump($_SESSION). The information for the name field doesn't seem to update unless I refresh the page. Is there a way to force the session to update without refreshing the page?

Comment: Ken, not without adding in some AJAX debugging, but I don't think it's worth it. For debugging purposes, you could add something like `$_SESSION['a'] = $_GET['a']` and verify that the session variable updates when you change the `?a=blah` parameter in the URL.

Comment: I've been using $_POST, but I can try to change things to $_GET for testing purposes.

Comment: have you tried a different key other than "name" ? could be that is somehow reserved by php for something.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how $_SESSION should work. Because same variable might be in use at different pages, and under processing and so changing values will be unacceptable.

In your case, you are trying to update $_SESSION['name'] and need to keep all other session values intact. The possible solution is

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['name']);//remove $_SESSION['name']
session_regenerate_id();//Copies all other session variables on to new id
$_SESSION["name"] = $newValue;//Create new session variable 'name'.
session_write_close();
?>
```